# DISTINCT and ORDER BY query not working in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server

We've migrated our database from MS SQL 2008 to SQL2012. 
After migration some of the queries does not working.
Below query is working with SQL2008 and SQL2000 but does not working with SQL2012

```
SELECT DISTINCT Field1, Field1+ ' - ' + Field1 as Field1 FROM TABLE ORDER BY Field1
```

Msg 209, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Ambiguous column name 'MCH_GROUP'.

I know we can modify the queries but we've a lot of applications. 
I think there should be a path or a settings to execute this query without any error on sql 2012.

Comment: Can you show the *actual* query you're using? The "ambiguous column name" errors occur when you're joining tables that have the same column name and you're not aliasing them; your sample query has no such join (or a column named `MCH_GROUP` for that matter).

Comment: You have 2 field1 being returned and you are trying to order by the same name. change one of the names.

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT Field1, Field1+'-' +Field1 as Field11 FROM TABLE ORDER BY Field1
`

Answer (score 2):

The error comes due to the `order by` clause.
Server cannot distinguish between the two Field1 columns.
Please give a different name for 2nd column.

```
SELECT      DISTINCT Field1, 
            Field1+ ' - ' + Field1 as Field2 
FROM        TABLE 
ORDER BY    Field1

Another Eg:
SELECT      DISTINCT [FirstName], 
            [FirstName] + ' - ' + [FirstName]  As [TwiceFirstName]
FROM        [dbo].[DimCustomer]
ORDER BY    [FirstName]
```

Comment: While this is correct and is what the original poster should be doing to fix his issue, it doesn't actually answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT Field1, Field1+ ' - ' + Field1 as Field2 FROM TABLE ORDER BY Field1
```

You called 2 fields the same and then you are confusing the order by...

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
SELECT DISTINCT Field1, Field1+ ' - ' + Field1 as CalcualtedField FROM TABLE ORDER BY Field1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you absolutely cannot change the queries (which you should do) then set the compatibility level for the database to SQL2000. Right click database, Properties, Options, set `Compatibility level` to `SQL Server 2000 (80)`

Comment: The lowest compatibility level that SQL Server 2012 will run a database in is `2005 (90)`.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever OK, I didn't have 2012 instance to test and it worked fine on 2005. Ah well, OP has to change all the queries. Short term pain for long term gain.

Comment: Ok guys thanks for comments and suggestions, as I told you before we can modify the queries this is long way. Changing compatibility level is not suitable.

Comment: @Emre - the problem is that, someone (not necessarily you) has been *avoiding* an issue for a long time - these queries worked on a 2000 server, but not on a later one (I'd lay good money on a bet that your 2008 instance was running this database in 2000 compatibility mode). Well, now, finally, you've hit a point of being forced to change. The required changes could have been (gradually) performed over the last decade but they've not been - so now you need to accept the pain and make the changes.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever - All of the queries written by central team and we've not authorized to make change. When we catch an error, reporting central team and waiting for changes. As usual, in business this is teaser! After your comment, I've checked our test server's compatibility mode, you're right, it is 2000! As a result, we've to report all of the issues and should wait till they make change. Thanks for all comments.